# Error using preg_replace() to format link url

Tags: php

I have a multi link:

```
http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list&paged=2
http://test.com/?paged=2&sort=newest&v=list
```

And code php:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$actual_link = preg_replace("&paged=/\D/", "", $actual_link);
$actual_link = preg_replace("?paged=/\D/", "", $actual_link);
```

Result error `Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '&' found ...`

How to remove ?paged=xx And &paged=xx

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: You can use a whole bunch of stuff as delimiters. Here it thinks you took `&`. Solution: wrap all in `+`. `preg_replace("+&paged=/\D/+", "", $actual_link);`. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression must start and end with the symbol /, for example: 
preg_replace ("/&paged=\D/", "", $actual_link);.
You must also correct the variable $actual_link:
$actual_link = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
Without quotes will throw an error.

Comment: -1 for: Look at the link I posted. MUST... +1 for pointing to the missing `"/'` quotes!

Comment: DOC ASAREL, sorry, I'm new to stack, I have not seen the link

Comment: I mean, you have an error in your post. `The regular expression must` start with any of the delimiters from the link. ;) Good Sunday!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`preg_replace("/[&?]paged=\d/", "", $actual_link);`

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want: (notice the + after d in case of many digits)

```
 $link = preg_replace('/[&?]paged=\d+/', '', $link);
```

However, it might be nice to remove the & after so that http://test.com/?paged=2&sort=newest&v=list does not become http://test.com/&sort=newest&v=list (we have a useless & before sort)

The & at the end is optional. We can remove it like so:

```
$link = preg_replace('/[&?]paged=\d+[&]?/', '', $link);
```

Finally, are you sure you want to remove the ? at the beginning. Perhaps you need it before sort? So that http://test.com/?paged=2&sort=newest&v=list does not become http://test.com/sort=newest&v=list, but instead http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list

In that case, we make the & optional, and don't remove the ?.

```
$link = preg_replace('/[&]?paged=\d+[&]?/', '', $link);
```

---

Choose your poison wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick

```
$actual_link = "http://test.com/?sort=newest&v=list&paged=2";
$actual_link = preg_replace("/[&?]paged=\d/", "&paged=", $actual_link);
echo $actual_link;
```

Demo

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4d8392f4948513f8b0682081e717017eb40dea3